# Declarative derived properties for mutable models in Java

Tags: java, modeling, data-binding, declarative, frp

Is there a framework for synchronizing properties of POJOs? For example, I want to express (in some high-level, declarative form) that `foo.text = bar.text + baz.text` or `foo.y = (max(bars, y)).y` without having to register property change, element add and remove listeners on values and (especially) collections, which are repetitive and error-prone.

Comment: After further research, I learned that this is called Reactive Programming (RP), but not found any pure Java implementation (except of SugarCubes, which is very outdated).

Answer (score 2):

[javafx](http://www.javafx.com/) and it's [bind operator](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1/tutorials/core/dataBinding/). For example:

```
var x = 10;
var y = bind -x + 100;
assert y == 90;        // passes
y = 40;                // bind! 
assert x == 60;        // passes
```

for java take a look at [JSR 295](https://beansbinding.dev.java.net/)